# GeoModel in JRuby on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, geolocation, jruby

Is it possible to extend GeoModel class like in python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you mean 'has it been done', then the answer is no, not to the best of my knowledge.